# Why does my ListView have an additional row that below the header, and above the row with position 0?

Tags: android

How can I disable that? It seems to use the same layout passed in the constructor of the ArrayAdapter for the textResource arg. I would like to disable that (since I already have a header View), thanks!

Heres the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/atPUy.jpg

As you can see, row 0 is deliberately set to null, of which I display a different View, in this case, its the beige row saying "Checkpoints Near me".

Numbers 1-8 are the data rows. However, right above the beige row, I see another row. Of which I don't understand how it came about.

Heres the ArrayAdapter:

```
public class BrowserTabArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserCheckpointBean> {

    Context context;
    UserCheckpointBean[] data;

    public BrowserTabArrayAdapter(Context context, UserCheckpointBean[] data) {
        super(context, R.layout.checkpoint_tab_row, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public UserCheckpointBean[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        UserCheckpointBean bean = getItem(position);
        View rowView = null;

        if (bean == null) {
            rowView = new OptionBarContainer(context);
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkpoint_tab_row, parent,
                    false);
            TextView tv = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv));
            tv.setText(new Integer(position).toString());
            rowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setData(UserCheckpointBean[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a screenshot, perhaps some code?

Comment: i will post code once i get on my dev machine

Comment: and done! edited with code and screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Check twice your List adapter whether it returns right view for 0 position.

Comment: it returns a total of 9 views, even tho i have only 8 items in the array (For arrayadapter)

Comment: Do you provide your ArrayAdapter with entries? how much of them?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I accidentally added 2 header views. :X